# How to exclude hot-formula-parser from handsontable build?

Tags: handsontable

I'm using [handsontable](https://handsontable.com/) without formulas. However, hot-formula-parser is still included in a webpack build, since it's a dependency of handsontable. Is there a solid, non-hacky, way to get rid of this?

As can be seen it takes quite a bite of my total bundle size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your Webpack config:

```
{
    test: require.resolve('hot-formula-parser/dist/formula-parser.js'),
    use: 'ignore-loader'
}
```